# How to receive data posted by curl to my server

Tags: php, web-services, post, curl

I am trying to develop a webservice to provide some e-commerce solutions and for that i want users to post data via CURL to one of my VPS's server page.
I don't know how do i prepare my server page or server to receive those post data?
Is there any online service where i can register and can receive data there and then i can process those data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing to "prepare". A POST request through curl is no different then a POST request from a web browser. The user-agent may change but the requests all are the same. That's what standards are. *Standards*. If POST requests could be in a different form each time it was used interoperability would never happen and the world would be one big proprietary mess.

So, you would just get those values through `$_POST` like you would any other POST request.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is the array which can "accept" the values sent to the page via POST